# Error When Trying Sample In Accessing MongoDB Data with GORM

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-boot

I was following the tutorial for [Accessing MongoDB Data with GORM](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gorm-mongodb/) but I am having a problem with the sample Groovy code.  I copied the sample Groovy code into a file called app.groovy.  When I run the code from the spring boot cli the code works fine.  If I compile the code into a jar by running

```
spring jar my-app.jar *.groovy
```

and then running

```
java -jar my-app.jar
```

I get an IllegalStateException

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.jar.PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher.run(PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.jar.PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher.main(PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher.java:61)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cityController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [City] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [City] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at City.currentGormStaticApi(app.groovy)
    at City.withTransaction(app.groovy)
    at City$withTransaction.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at CityController.populateCities(app.groovy:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 27 more
```

Anyone have any idea how I fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you link to the GORM dependencies (e.g. a `@Grab`)?

Comment: The code in the tutorial uses @Grab("org.grails:gorm-mongodb-spring-boot:1.0.0.RC1")

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/686. Maybe a classloader thing, I'm not sure, but we'll look at it and update here when it's fixed. You should be able to use the Gradle or Maven build to create an executable JAR in the meantime.

Update: we might be able to fix this in Spring Boot and/or GORM, but in the meantime if you just declare a package in your `app.groovy` (e.g. `package app`) it should work.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I will try the Java Maven approach and see if that works.

Comment: You can't use GORM with Java (so at least the domain objects are going to have to be Groovy). The gs-guide source code has a pom.xml that worked last time I looked though.

Comment: Sorry meant Groovy ;)

Comment: The Maven example worked.  As a heads up though the links in that tutorial point to github repo that does not appear to be related to the code shown in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. You can raise issues with the guide in its tracker: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gorm-mongodb/issues